# Connect Middleware Node.js Max File Size

Tags: node.js, ftp, node.js-connect

I have an FTP portal built on node.js. When uploading a file over 100MB, i get an error.

Here is the error output:

```
{"error":{"message":"Request Entity Too Large","stack":"Error: Request         Entity Too Large\n 
at Object.exports.error (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:62:13)\n
at limit (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/limit.js:46:47)\n
at multipart (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:97:5)\n
at /home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:57:9\n 
at urlencoded (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:52:72)\n 
at /home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:55:7\n 
at json (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:46:55)\n at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:53:5)\n 
at next (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)\n 
at Object.cookieParser [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/sasite-ftp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js:60:5)","status":413}}
```

I looked inside connect/lib/middleware/limit.js at lines 46 and 47:

```
     if (len && len > bytes) return next(utils.error(413));
```

Which seems to be related to this function in limit.js:

```
module.exports = function limit(bytes){
if ('string' == typeof bytes) bytes = utils.parseBytes(bytes);
if ('number' != typeof bytes) throw new Error('limit() bytes required');
return function limit(req, res, next){
var received = 0
  , len = req.headers['content-length']
    ? parseInt(req.headers['content-length'], 10)
    : null;
```

I can post some more code if need be, however you can easily lookup the code for connect in node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/

If anyone has any input on what the maximum file size actually is, and what the restrictions on it are, it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: the max file size is 100MB, in what file do I enter the code to change this as per the first the answer below's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Connect multipart middleware one way or another, the default maximum upload file size is 100MB, as defined here:

```
var limit = _limit(options.limit || '100mb');
```

If you want to set your own file upload limit, the multipart middleware has a `limit` option you can set:

```
app.use(connect.multipart({
  limit: '1000mb'
}));
```

If you are using `connect.bodyParser()`, it also uses the multipart middleware internally so the option can be specified the same way:

```
app.use(connect.bodyParser({
  limit: '1000mb'
}));
```

Comment: Please note that `bodyParser` is deprecated and will be removed in the next version of Express, thus shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Before I accept, can you help me out by explaining where I should add that code?  In the node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/middleware/limit.js file?  Or somewhere else?

Comment: @paul-mougel Is there any documentation for that? Do you know what the alternative implementation is?

Comment: I believe i was wrong: `bodyParser` isn't deprecated, but is uses `multipart` that is deprecated, so the behavior of `bodyParser` will change when connect 3.0 lands. Basically, `multipart` will be removed, so you'll have to use something else such as formidable or busboy. See [the wiki page for Connect 3.0](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

From the connect-multiparty Express Middleware [connect-multipart/index.js](https://github.com/expressjs/connect-multiparty/blob/master/index.js):

- The options passed are merged with [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty)'s
  `Form` object, allowing you to configure the upload directory,
  size limits, etc. For example if you wish to change the upload dir do the following.

So according to [Multiparty Docs](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty):

- maxFieldsSize - Limits the amount of memory all fields (not files) can      allocate in bytes. If this value is exceeded, an error event is emitted. The default size is 2MB.

I got mine working with:

```
var app = express(),
    multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

app.use(multipart({
    maxFieldsSize: '20MB'
}));
```

Comment: hello @gtrenco how to handle error event in it? because it is going into infinite